# Can't send my tezos around because of a "transaction failed" error

Tags: transactions, error

I have my Tezos inside tezbox, but whenever I try to send them I get a "failed transactions" error. See details [here](https://tzscan.io/KT1RqWRyZrkmzqSRtywY9gHYarRZquiGzrvo).

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The error occurred because I needed to have some balance left to complete the transaction. It works fine after that.